# d3.js run as app with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, d3.js, sencha-cmd

Anyone know the commands to make my d3.js directory a cordova project and then run it on a device? When using Sencha cmd I ran `sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp` to create the project, then `sencha app run native` to run the app on my device. But what's the commands for d3.js?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting the concept wrong. `sencha` provides you a command line tool, that wraps cordova/phonegap commands and provides additional goodies. `d3.js` is a library and does not come with a command line tool such as `sencha`. What you need to do is use cordova/phonegap commands inside your `d3.js` directory to create/build and run the project on your device.

- `phonegap create my-app` initializes project
- `phonegap local run android` adds, builds and runs project on your android device.

For more details check the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).